# Energy simulation of a RISC-V chip

Tags: riscv

Can the RISC-V simulators estimate the energy consumption of a Rocket chip?

For instance, is there a way to produce traces that can be fed to McPAT?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To estimate Rocket Chip's energy, we use Chisel's Verilog backend to  generate RTL which we feed into CAD tools for gate-level simulation.

The simulators provided by Berkeley (QEMU, Rocket Chip, spike) currently do not support interfacing with McPAT, but this could be a great community contribution for those without access to CAD tools or wanting to simulate at a higher rate.